# 13.75ns CL in Dual Rank vs 12.5ns CL in Single Rank (2Rx8 vs 1Rx8)

Tags: laptop, motherboard, memory, ryzen

Which would be a better choice for gaming/video editing in a 32GB SODIMM kit (2x16GB) on HP Victus running Ryzen 5600H:

A higher CAS latency on a dual rank (& dual channel) memory or a lower CAS latency on a single rank (also dual channel) memory?

https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KF432S20IBK2_16.pdf

https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KVR32S22D8_16.pdf

Are there any benchmarks that indicate precisely the ups and downs of dual rank memory?

Thanks!